# Using loop to get values from JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtextfield

I going to create a program with Java. It's the interactive quicksort simulator. Firstly, you have to input the number of integers that you want to sort. After press next, there will be textfields which number according to the number that you have put at first, ie. if you put 15, there will be 15 textfields for you to input the numbers. If you put 20, there will be 20 textfields for you. After press next, those values will be stored in an array which its size equal to the number from the 1st place.

My problem is, the textfields have to be named (ie. jtextfield0 to jtextfield15) and to get the value frome the textfield to be stored in the array, It has to be like

```
 a[0] = jtextfield0.getValue();
 a[1] = jtextfield1.getValue();
```

and so on. This way, it's so brute forced and inflexible.

How can I use loop to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add your textfields into `ArrayList` and perform a loop over this `ArrayList`:

```
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
...
//add your textfields to arraylist
...
for(int i = 0;i< textFields.size(); i++){
  fields[i] = textFields.get(i).getValue();
}
```

Comment: But I have to add the JTextFields into the arraylist manually first right becuase different JTextFields have different variable names (ie. jTextField1, jTextField2, etc)? Is there anyway to do it using loop?

Comment: using loop, no or is so difficult

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `array` or `List<T>` of objects.

Array of objects:

```
JTextField fields[]=new JTextField[15];

for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
 {
   fields[i]=new JTextField(5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case to add array of JTextFields to ArrayList:

textFields.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));

Comment: Sorry, realized that the question was asked more than a year ago, but maybe some can profit